# How to make Guard-less to watch for multiple files but compile just one?

Tags: less, guard

when I add less to the Guardfile like so:

guard 'less', :output => 'css/' do 
      watch(%r{^less/(.+.less)$})
     end

since I have multiple less files, imported them all in one less file, and I want watch all of them but to compile just one, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom function and test if the css file matching your less file is older. If not then compile the file - the first matched file is compiled by less and all linked less files will have newer css files and therefore will not be processed.

Comment: Any examples of how to do actually do so?